# CSS flexbox child behavior

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hey I'm new to html and css, I want to do something but I can't find anywhere how to do it, or maybe I'm not understanding well, I made a codepen with an example: https://codepen.io/chileseco/pen/rNemRoZ and this is what I need: http://prntscr.com/u7aw4v or I need more than just flex display?

Thanks for your attention!

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 255);
}
.child1{  
  background-color: rgb(240, 104, 104);
}
.child2{  
  background-color: rgb(115, 243, 115);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child1">
    <h1>Child 1</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="child2">
    <h1>Child 2</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a more specific behavior. Note offtopic: you should not use more than 1 `<h1>`, make them `<h2>` or something. Several `<h1>` will confuse screenreaders.

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 255);
  /*height and Width, padding and margin for display example, you can set that how you need*/
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.child1{ 
  /*Aligning the headings inside the divs*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(240, 104, 104);
  width: 40%;
}
.child2{ 
  /*Aligning the headings inside the divs*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(115, 243, 115);
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child1">
    <h1>Child 1</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="child2">
    <h1>Child 2</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the h1 tip, it was just as example but I didn't know it anyways. Nice anwser.

Comment: No problem thats what we are here for :)

Comment: You can unify communal declarations of both children elements: ```.child1, .child2 {display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;}```. The last two can be replaced with ```place-items: center;```.

Answer (score 2):

Add to `child1`

```
.child1{  
  display: flex;
  flex: 40%;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Add to `child2`

```
.child1{  
  display: flex;
  flex: 60%;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 255);
}

.child1{  
  display: flex;
  flex: 40%;
  background-color: rgb(240, 104, 104);
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.child2{  
  display: flex;
  flex: 60%;
  background-color: rgb(115, 243, 115);
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child1">
    <h1>Child 1</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child2">
    <h1>Child 2</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use flex attribute in child elements.

```
.parent{
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 255);
  min-height:100vh;
}
.child1{ 
  flex:0.4;
  background-color:rgb(240, 104, 104);
}
.child2{  
  flex:0.6;
  background-color: rgb(115, 243, 115);
}
```

Comment: min-height! I also needed this, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
.parent{
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 255);
  height: 1000px;
}
.child1{
  flex: 40%;
  display:flex;
  background-color: rgb(240, 104, 104);
}
.child2{  
  flex: 60%;
  display:flex;
  background-color: rgb(115, 243, 115);
}
```

Comment: yes thank you, but I also need them to fill the all the height

Comment: @MarioJose Edited it. Just add the desired height.

Comment: Warden down there has a complete example.

Comment: Please add each child to `display:flex;` for take the style `flex`

Comment: @RubixOverflow I have seen yours and Wardens answer. Way more extensive and therefore better.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `flex: 60%` and `flex:40%` to your children

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I add 100% width to your parent element

```js
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 255);
}
```

Then I add 40% to first child and 60% to second child. Also there is a new nice way to center elements. It's the combination of two css rules: `display: grid;` to enable the second rule, which is `place-items: center;`

```js
.child1 {  
  background-color: rgb(240, 104, 104);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 40%;
}
.child2 {  
  background-color: rgb(115, 243, 115);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 60%
}
```

What is more you can add `height: 100vh;` to make the parent element expand to the height of your viewport

```js
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 255);
}
```

The whole code:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 255);
}

.child1 {
  background-color: rgb(240, 104, 104);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 40%;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: rgb(115, 243, 115);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 60%
}
```